# Facebook url debugger showing correct share modal for dev server page but invalid for production server page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my Dev Server Link https://greenrobot.com/pirates/fbdev/completed_quest.php, which i want to share on facebook. And this is for production server share https://greenrobot.com/pirates/fb/completed_quest.php.

when i see this in facebook url debugger (https(colon)//developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and fetch as new scrap information it is showing everything correct. Now i move all code to live and there are just link change from fbdev to fb. And for production url url debugger keeps saying

"Object at URL 'https(colon)//greenrobot.com/pirates/fb/completed_quest.php' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided."

However, when you see meta tags by view source you can see exactly same tags on production and dev server.

Any idea why it is doing so? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
You need to use ob_start() if you are doing window.top.location(facebook_login_url) and die()/exit(); Otherwise your output will be having warnings of sessions_start() and set_cookie() from src/facebook.php and src/base_facebook.php

Comment: There are no OG meta tags in what your server initially delivers: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgreenrobot.com%2Fpirates%2Ffb%2Fcompleted_quest.php – it only contains a script element to redirect to the login dialog. (Which is bad UX btw., your app should not automatically redirect to the login dialog, but rather only on explicit user interaction.)

Comment: Thank for your comment @CBroe. Actually this app starts from https://greenrobot.com/pirates. So i am not worried about that much. Have  you tried to access this page after login and seen meta tags on development and production server links?

Comment: _“Have you tried to access this page after login”_ – no, I have not. And the Facebook scraper does not “log in” to your site either. So your meta tags have to be present before login.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe now got the point. Same kind of response i get from facebook over here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/966059006822490/